# facing issues while enrolling the user certificate in fabric cop server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm getting error as rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure while i try to register the user through rest client... please provide me the possible solution as soon as possible...i followed the below link to configure cop server please let me know the configuration is right or not.
https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric-cop
and the attachment conatins directories involved in configuration:
 [directories involved in configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh8Yl.png)

Answer (score 1):

We renamed "fabric-cop" to "fabric-ca" so you are using an outdated version of the code.  I'd suggest taking a look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca as that's the latest code

Comment: Gari, Thank you for this information. Although http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Setup/ca-setup/#build-and-run still points to fabric repo with "make membersrvc" command. It would be nice to add comment or information about this change from fabric-cop to fabric-ca in https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1001 and in documentation.